# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<....>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How to return 404 when there is no row found? However, the following code got an error on line `return NotFound()`.

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< webapi.Models.Product>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByReportId(int rid)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var query = from b in db.table where b.rid == rid select b;
            if (query == null)
            {
                return NotFound(); // Error!
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A suggested read: [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling).

Comment: It's worth noting that query will never be null -- it's a definition. The query's results will also never be null -- it would be empty. Check for the right things while you're going about fixing your main issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set/cast *System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult* to a *Product*.

You have to modify the calling method to return a 404 (or a message) when the result of GetProductsByReportId is null.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByReportId(int rid)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var query = from b in db.table where b.rid == rid select b;
            if (query == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

i.e.

```
int id = 1;
List<Product> products = GetProductsByReportId(id);
if(products == null) {
    var message = string.Format("Product with id = {0} not found", id);
    HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all.

You're trying to return the object `System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult` when your method signature is to return `IEnumerable<Product>`

One thing you could do is something like:

```
if (query == null)
     return null;
```

Then in the code that is calling this method, handle the fact that the list is empty.

As you mentioned in your tags, asp.net Web api, you can do something like this in your controller (assuming your controller is returning `HttpResponseMessage`):

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProducts(int id)
{
    var prods = GetProductsByReportId(id);
    if (prods == null)             
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, prods);
}
```